# Не Могу сделать выборку с базы данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, выборка

Делаю вот такую выборку с базы

```
$result_likes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes_order 
WHERE user_sex='$user_sex' or user_sex='$user_sex_nan' AND 
user_country='$user_country' or user_country='$user_country_nan' AND 
order_user_uid!='$user_uid' ");
```

Но не работает! В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Выборка происходит только по одному параметру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скобки Ваша проблема:

```
SELECT * FROM likes_order WHERE 
(user_sex='$user_sex' or user_sex='$user_sex_nan') AND 
(user_country='$user_country' or user_country='$user_country_nan') AND 
order_user_uid!='$user_uid
```

И, наверное, понятней еще вот так:

```
SELECT * FROM likes_order WHERE 
user_sex IN ('$user_sex', '$user_sex_nan') AND 
user_country IN ('$user_country', '$user_country_nan') AND 
order_user_uid!='$user_uid
```

Comment: Вот етоя  тормознул, спасибо большое за помощ